# Apostrophe turning out as a '6' instead of a '9'

Tags: hyperlink

You know how with "quotation marks" -- with some fonts, the first mark in the set is shaped like the digit '6' and the last mark in the set is shaped like the digit '9'...

…and an apostrophe is shaped like a digit '9'…

Well, I have an apostrophe that's shaping out as a 6 instead of a 9.

It's in the second paragraph here: http://richardclunan.com/copywriter/

It's right after a hyperlink. I don't want to include the apostrophe in the hyperlink, and I prefer to keep the copy as it is.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: It looks like a straight apostrophe to me, rather than a 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are typing non-smart straight vertical apostrophe and your CMS system is converting it to a "smart apostrophe".  Because your possessive is broken up by a link, the CMS system appears to be choosing the apostrophe for starting a quoted section rather than the one for a possessive `s`.

You could try:

- Inserting the correct smart apostrophe yourself.  Copy and paste in a `’` rather than using a straight non-smart apostrophe.
- Inserting the HTML entity reference for the correct smart apostrophe.  Put in `&rsquo;`.  You would probably have to insert this into the "source code view" of your post rather than the "what you see is what you get" view of your post.
- If all else fails, remove the link and link the entire word (including the `'s`) instead.

For more information about smart quotes see [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs).